# DHTMLX tree structure combo box using json

Tags: dhtml, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I want a tree structure dropdown with checkbox.!. I can achieve this structure image but i want exact tree structure. Someone help me out.

[Achieve image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUT0j.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality in dhtmlxCombo to do this, but you can add needed margin b using item's css.